# Closing </script> tag breaks the script

Tags: javascript, html

This one's just got me confused. Live in action examples are at the bottom of this post.

At the end of my document is some `<script`> tags.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js">
```

The final script tag is unclosed. This code works when it remains unclosed. However, when I  add the closing `</script`> tag, the code no longer works.

This is really confusing me and I don't know how to troubleshoot this. 
If I delete the `<script src="js/dropdown.js">`, and I delete the closing `</script>` tag for offcanvas.js, then offcanvas.js stops working.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js"> </script>
```

The above doesnt work. So why does dropdown.js work without a closing script tag, and offcanvas.js will not?

I am not sure what I'm missing. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

PS 
After the script tags it just closes out, `</body> </html>`

Live in Action At The Following:

WORKING: http://mammola.info/testing/bootstrap/

NOT WORKING: http://mammola.info/testing/bootstrap/index-notwork.php

Comment: Does your code validate in the W3C validator when the closing script tag is present?

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: Post a reproducible example.

Comment: Can we see this in action?

Comment: after `<script src="js/dropdown.js">` what is there

Comment: Console says event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: u can see it in action http://mammola.info/bootstrap/

Comment: how can you differentiate whether it was working or not?

Comment: the 'dropdown' element works if the code works. The menu navigation with the expandable menu works if the code works.

Comment: Can you put up both versions of the page, one with the closing tag and one without?

Comment: the dropdown menu was working fine even I closed the script of dropdown.js

Comment: WORKING: http://mammola.info/bootstrap/
NOT WORKING: http://mammola.info/bootstrap/index-notwork.php

Comment: Remove the space from the body of your ```<script src="js/dropdown.js"> </script>``` tag.

Comment: @DarthJDG: That's irrelevant.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, could be. It needed closing anyway, the question is not useful for anyone else. There shouldn't be a space there, if for nothing else, consistency. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample *where it's working*, the **dropdown.js** is never executed (try setting breakpoints), the dropdown seen is the default jquery action.

Your code has problems. So when it's correctly included, the dropdown actions don't work correctly.

The screenshot below is from the second case where js is included correctly. And the line highlighted below is most probably the problem.

[image]

Comment: I actually came to the opposite conclusion: In the page that works, `dropdown.js` is not executed at all (it appears to be loaded, but a breakpoint set on line 26 isn't reached). The working page loads and executes `dropdown.js` just fine though. That's why assume that there is a conflict between `dropdown.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` and `dropdown.js` is actually not needed.

Comment: Ohh, so dumb of me to have written the opposite after doing all the debugging :P.  I have to remove the not...Thanks for pointing out, you are absolutely correct & I meant the same.

Comment: O wow... Yea. I just remove the dropdown.js and then the "dropdown" menu functionality works just fine!